# MVC 3 templates translations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, localization

Is there place where I can find translations of t4 templates asp.net mvc 3 uses to scaffold views?

Comment: What you mean by translations?

Comment: @archil I mean, when I create view, it contains some text in English, but I would like them to be in russian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [Mvc3CodeTemplatesCSharp](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Mvc3CodeTemplatesCSharp) package on Nuget that you can install and then modify.
Also, you could further read [Modifying the default code generation/scaffolding templates in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ModifyingTheDefaultCodeGenerationscaffoldingTemplatesInASPNETMVC.aspx) by Scott Hanselman for mode info